# Php query is not returning anything not even echo from if statement when it is empty

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I am running into a problem, i am trying to just query a table and get some result back, if there is no result(empty) then it just echo it is empty.

The problem is, before the `while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))` echo works with no problem. But when it is inside the while loop, it echos nothing back, not even `if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==0)echo 'There is nothing';` or if i do

```
if(empty($result)){
echo "There is no";
```

Here is my code below, thanks for your time

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

session_start();
include 'connect.php';


echo "It is working";

$Listingid = "648";


echo "$Listingid";


$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM list WHERE Listingid = '$Listingid'")
    or die(mysqli_error($con));


while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if(empty($result)) {
        echo "There is no";
    } else {
        echo 'User ID:' . $row['userid'] . '<br>Username:' . $row['username'] . '<br>Useremail:' . $row['useremail'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Add `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your code for better error reporting

Comment: I just added it, no error

Comment: The problem may be your `ob_start();` So you start buffering but never send the buffered output (e.g. `echo`) to the browser.

Comment: Then update your question. I'd also get rid of the `ob_start()`; you have no use for it

Comment: Try to put `if(empty($result))` BEFORE the `while`-loop, because if `$result` is empty, it won't jump into the `while`-loop.

Comment: I just tried removing the ob_start() and tried the answer below, it is still the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this logic

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con,"select count(*) as count from list WHERE Listingid = '$Listingid'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
{
    $count = $row['count'];
}

if($count == 0)
{
   echo 'it is empty';
}
else
{
$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM list WHERE Listingid = '$Listingid'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo 'User ID:'.$row['userid'].'<br>Username:'.$row['username'].'<br>Useremail:'.$row['useremail'];
}
}
```

Comment: Just tried this! It is now echoing the it is empty part!

Comment: Can you briefly explain why my code didnt work? Or what the difference is

Comment: @user3829266 `$result` is your `mysqli_result` object from the query. Given a successful query, this will never be *empty*. What your code did not do was detect zero results

Comment: first query will retutn you the occurance of records for Listingid = '$Listingid' condition. If $count = 0 ,it means no records are present for that condition. Else record exists and show record using second sql query.

Comment: There is a syntax error on line 13. The semicolon is missing. It isn't recommended to use two querys for this.

Comment: @yannici - thanx. but my intention was to suggest just logic. I didnt hardcoded it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

session_start();
include 'connect.php';


echo "It is working";

$Listingid = "648";


echo "$Listingid";


$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM list WHERE Listingid = '$Listingid'");

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    echo "There is no";
} else {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo 'User ID:' . $row['userid'] . '<br>Username:' . $row['username'] . '<br>Useremail:' . $row['useremail'];
    }
}
?>
```

It checks, if there is data **before** the `while`-loop, because it won't go through the `while`-loop if it doesn't find any result with this query.

Answer (score -1):

have you tried using `mysqli_fetch_array();` instead of `mysqli_fetch_assoc();`?
`mysqli_fetch_array();` fetches all fields while `mysqli_fetch_assoc();` returns field names with row values, not names ex:

```
[0] => "Username", [1] =>"Email"
```

while `mysqli_fetch_array();`
 returns:

```
[0] => "username", [Username] => "username, [1] => "Email", [Email] => "Email"
```

and this part:

```
if(empty($result)) {
    echo "There is no";
}
```

is quite useless, since if there wasn't a row, the loop wouldn't come at this point of the script.

Comment: It should still echo something out tho right? It should still echo out "There is no" It is not even echoing that

Comment: Nope, because it doesn't detect the fieldnames "userid" and "username"

Comment: Modified my first post.